# How to infer redux toolkit query error return type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

`getCommonError()` is strongly typed as

```
type CommonErrorType = {
}

 const something = useDosomethingQuery()
//something.error should be CommonErrorType
```

I want to infer the return type in the hook. I have tried a couple of options, type erasure of rtk query, generics of `fakeBaseQuery` which was a bit closer but then `queryFn` did not like that and emitted some gibberish any help will be appreciated. What I don't want to do is cast the error every time from `unknown` to `CommonErrorType`

```
const api = createApi({
      baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
      ...,
      endpoints: build => ({
        dosomething: build.query<Result, param>({
          queryFn: async () => {
            try {
              const data = await doSomething();
              return { data };
            } catch (error) {
              // getCommonError() is strongly typed as type CommonErrorType
              return getCommonError(error);
            }
          }
        }),
```